# Svelte if block's behavior is different form component's property when is set to undefined

Tags: undefined, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I prefer to define a `visible` property for Svelte components rather than writing Svelte's `if block` in template. In my opinion, it is more clean to set a `visible` property instead of adding 2 lines of if block codes in the template.

I am trying to define a `visible` property for a Svelte component which **must** have the same behavior of `if` block.

[Here is the repl.](https://svelte.dev/repl/d73c70e6586a4dffa7ed30e19b95436b?version=3.47.0)

**El.svelte**

```
<script>
    export let visible = true // should be visible by default
</script>

{#if visible}
<svelte:element this="div" {...$$restProps}>
    <slot />
</svelte:element>
{/if}
```

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import El from './El.svelte';   
    let visible = undefined
</script>
<El {visible}>Component (undefined)</El>
{#if visible}
    Svelte if block (undefined)
{/if}
```

The if block is working as expected, but the component is rendered which shouldn't be.

It seems that undefined property isn't passed to component during Svelte compilation.

*What is the best way to make consistent behavior for `visible` property?*

**Update:**

The reason I want to use as visible property is the final code is more readable. Here is a sample code using if block:

```
{#if invoice.payment}
  {#if invoice.payment?.approved}
    <Badge>Approved</Badge>
    {#if !order.confirmed}
      <Button>Void Payment</Button>
    {/if}
  {/if}
  {#if invoice.payment?.status }
    <b>{invoice.payment.tranasction.id}</b>
  {/if}
{/if}
```

And using `visible` property:

```
<Div visible={invoice.payment?.approved}>
  <Badge>Approved</Badge>
  <Button visible={!order.confirmed}>Void Payment</Button>
</Div>
<B visible={invoice.payment?.status}>{invoice.payment.tranasction.id}</B>
```

[The updated repl to support all scenarios.](https://svelte.dev/repl/30b621995f434bb19de73785c3ae3e83?version=3.47.0)

But I'm not sure if it's correct implementation or future usage in nested components and event/property/action bindings.

**Update 2:**

I don't think this is a my-opinion-based usage: [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-6) has `v-if` and
[Angular](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp) has `ng-if` that does the same thing as `visible`.

Comment: You're setting it to undefined might be the issue. Default prop values are a little weird in svelte.

Comment: It works fine if a value (null, 1, 0, true, etc.) is set to the property except undefined. But, I have many if blocks like `{#if invoice.payment?. status}` and I want to use the conditions in the property.

Comment: If a property is set to `undefined` or not defined at all, the default in the component is used, so this is not going to work. Also, I would not recommend this approach at all, you are fighting the system.

Comment: @H.B. please see this [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/30b621995f434bb19de73785c3ae3e83?version=3.47.0). It works fine in all scenarios. But, I'm not sure if it is the right implementation.

Comment: Why don't you just use a css class with `display: none / visibility: hidden` to hide the elements (div, button, b,..)? The component in your examples doesn't even seem to hold any logic that justifies the wrapping inside a component..? But there's a lot of complexity added.

Comment: @Corrl `display: none / visibility: hidden` just hides the Html element, but the component is rendered in DOM. Assume that you have multiple complex components which should be rendered based on users access level. Also, how about SSR, I think the result will be sent to client and user can see the content in browser's source code section?

Comment: @AmirPournasserian: Regarding the note on `v-if` and `ng-if`: That is just their equivalent of Svelte's `{#if}` because they do not have special syntax that lives "outside" of elements besides interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stick with this approach (which I would not recommend - just use `{#if}` when you need it), then the best way to deal with this might be to not allow `undefined` to ever be passed as a value, because that resolves to the default set in the component (in this case `visible = true`).

So if you have a value that is potentially undefined, make sure it resolves to either `true` or `false`, e.g.

```html
<El visible={visible ?? false}>
```

Edit in response to question update: Using property inspection is indeed a working approach, though I would not allow arbitrary values, only `boolean`, `null` or `undefined`. The simplest setup for this would be:

```js
export let visible = undefined;
if ('visible' in $$props == false)
    visible = true;
```

A reactive statement is not required in this case, because whether a property is defined at all does not change. (This requires setting `visible={false}` instead of `visible="false"`.)

---

One reason to not do this at all is the use of `$$restProps`, as [the docs state](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-attributes-and-props):

> It shares the same optimisation problems as `$$props`, and is likewise not recommended.

Also, you will run into issues if you want to do event handling.

Comment: I have updated the question for the usage. Also you can see the updated repl. If I use this approach, what will be the issues in future?

Comment: Well, as noted it might degrade performance and since it wraps things, all events have to be manually forwarded because as of now there is no way to just forward all of them.

Comment: Auto event forwarding to child components is another concern, but does the visible property affect that? If a component is invisible,  events won't be binded/used, correct? This property is used for visual elements, not for behaviors/actions.

Comment: Well, if you restrict the use to only layout elements and not things like `input` and `button` then you might not need the events. Though even for layout sometimes things like hover or drag events may be useful. Of course you can forward those as needed later.

Comment: It is not used for layout elements: `El` is used as base component to define some basic behaviors and reduce the duplicate code for the main components (like `Button`, `Badge`, etc.). Here is the sample [`Button` repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/7cf11850fa48488b8b083e0b80afb1cd?version=3.47.0).

Comment: @AmirPournasserian That is not ideal, because then `El` probably needs to be adjusted a lot for various uses, which breaks its encapsulation.